# I can't get the content in page template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my custom page template "portfolio template", I try to get title and content (from text editor). I can get the title, but content returns as empty string ("").

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio Template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

    $portfolio_template_title = get_the_title();
    $portfolio_template_content = get_the_content();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't concerned with getting the loop, you appear to have omitted the 'echo' to show those values.

```
echo $portfolio_template_title;
echo $portfolio_template_content;
```

ought to output those variables for ya.

Comment: also get_the_content() will not do many of the things you may be intending to do (expand shortcodes, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I echo it for sure. I think my mistake is the lack of loop.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is the lack of loop. I was expecting the page template to bring content and title automatically.

Comment: So you added `the_post();` somewhere?

Comment: I didn't and this is a mistake. I was expecting template page to act like a view in MVC architecture was expecting to access all page related data without any loop, this is my mistake.

Comment: Yeah, this one has caught me a few times too. :)